# Get MaxLength value in .cshtml template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvc-editor-templates

In my class I have..

```
public class MyModel
{
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my view..

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

And my String.cshtml

```
@model string
@{ 
    // How to cetn MaxValue here ??
}

@Html.TextBox(Html.IdForModel().ToString(), Model, new { @class= "text-box single-line", placeholder=ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some basic code to get an attribute off a property.

```
// use a nullable int to remember (or use a regular int and set a default, whatever your use-case is)
int? maxLength;
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(MyModel).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    foreach (object attr in attrs)
    {
        MaxLengthAttribute maxLengthAttr = attr as MaxLengthAttribute;
        if (maxLengthAttr != null &&  prop.Name.Equals("Name"))
        {

            maxLength = maxLengthAttr.Length
        }
    }
}

// check to make sure you got a value. opti
if (maxLength.HasValue)
{
// whatever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the StringLength attribute you can use the AdditionalMetadata attribute.

```
[AdditionalMetadata("MaxLength", 30)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Your custom editor template (String.cshtml):

```
@{
    string max = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("MaxLength")
        ? ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["MaxLength"].ToString() : null;
}

@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { maxlength = max })
```

And then you can use :

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
```